# CSS transition on filter property

Tags: css, image, filter, css-transitions

I'm trying to apply an easing transition so that my shopping cart image goes from white to blue.

Without the transition, the white to blue effect works but without any kind of easing.

The issue is with the "all" transition property, it's creating a rainbow effect where you'll see streaks of green for a brief second then finally the blue. I'm not sure if you're able to call out separate filters (couldn't find anything googling) like brightness and saturate on their own.

Here's what I've currently got:

```
.top-register .register-image img:hover {
    filter: sepia(100%) contrast(100%) saturate(100) brightness(60%) hue-rotate(130deg);
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the transition to work you need to add the filters in element without :hover but in a way that is almost invisible

example:

```
.top-register .register-image img {
 filter: sepia(0.1%) contrast(100%) saturate(1) brightness(100%) 
   hue-rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;;
 }


.top-register .register-image img:hover {
 filter: sepia(100%) contrast(100%) saturate(100) brightness(60%) 
   hue-rotate(130deg);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;;
 }
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm still seeing the green streaks but I see what you're saying